# Parsing multiple files at a time in Perl

Tags: perl, performance, parsing, file, memory-management

I have a large data set (around 90GB) to work with. There are data files (tab delimited) for each hour of each day and I need to perform operations in the entire data set. For example, get the share of OSes which are given in one of the columns. I tried merging all the files into one huge file and performing the simple count operation but it was simply too huge for the server memory.

So, I guess I need to perform the operation each file at a time and then add up in the end. I am new to perl and am especially naive about the performance issues. How do I do such operations in a case like this.

As an example two columns of the file are.

```
ID      OS
1       Windows
2       Linux
3       Windows
4       Windows
```

Lets do something simple, counting the share of the OSes in the data set. So, each .txt file has millions of these lines and there are many such files. What would be the most efficient way to operate on the entire files.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're reading the entire file into memory, I don't see why the size of the file should be an issue.

```
my %osHash;

while (<>)
{
   my ($id, $os) = split("\t", $_);
   if (!exists($osHash{$os}))
   {
      $osHash{$os} = 0;
   }
   $osHash{$os}++;
}

foreach my $key (sort(keys(%osHash)))
{
   print "$key : ", $osHash{$key}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: You don't have to check whether the key exists before incrementing the value; if it doesn't yet exist it will be created on the spot.

Comment: @canavanin, will it be initialized to zero?  I've never tested that.

Comment: There's also no need for the parents in sort keys %osHash; Or to use $_ in a split, as it uses that by default; Also camelcase makes a fairly big subset of Perlers cringe, so you might want to avoid that.

Comment: @Hugmeir: I recommend 'parens' as the abbreviation for 'parentheses' because 'parents' is a perfectly good word in English (even in computing terms) that has a wholly different meaning.

Comment: Yes - the key is initialized to zero; it also triggers no warnings under warnings or strict.

Comment: I write my perl to look as much like Java as I can.  I know that makes hard core perl people cry, but when you jump between languages a lot it's easier not to have to memorize which ones require braces around the results of an `if` and which ones don't require brackets.

Answer (score 1):

While Paul Tomblin's answer dealt with filling the hash, here's the same plus opening the files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my @files = map { "file$_.txt" } 1..10;

my %os_count;

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$file>) {
        my ($id, $os) = split /\t/;
        ... #Do something with %os_count and $id/$os here.
    }
}
```

We just open each file serially -- Since you need to read all lines from all files, there isn't much more you can do about it. Once you have the hash, you could store it somewhere and load it when the program starts, then skip all lines until the last you read, or simply [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) there, if your records premit, which doesn't look like it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you pass the file names on the command line, won't they be accessible to <>, or is that only if you redirect stdin?

Comment: You are correct. Your solution works perfectly (unless you want encodings, but meh), and even does error checking automatically for you, which my solution had to get through autodie - I'm just showing it a bit more explicitly. It's also slightly more scalable, since it might show up in the middle of a proggy where something else already clobbered ARGV.